# Custom WordPress Shortcode, can't replace echo with return

Tags: php, wordpress, return, echo, shortcode

This code works great when put directly into the content of a page.

```
<font color=#ff0000> 
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

    echo $current_user->display_name . "\n"; 
    echo 'Level: ' . $current_user->level . "\n <br>";

?>
</font>
```

Result shows 'Sam level 65'

However, when I convert it to a shortcode and try to replace echo with return, wordpress breaks, all screens go blank.
This is an example of what i've tried:

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode() {

// Code
<font color=#ff0000> 
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  $output = $current_user->display_name . "\n"; 
  $output .= 'Level: ' . $current_user->level . "\n <br>";

return $output;

?>
</font>
}
add_shortcode( 'userlevel', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your error log? Does it provide any clues?

Comment: Can you add the error log to your question?

Comment: Error logs point to the last line.

It says 'Call to undefined function add_shortcode() etc.

I do not see how this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using HTML where PHP is expected. That's why you have a blank screen.

Here's how I'd move this into a shortcode:

```
function wpse_shortcode_userlevel() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    $output = '<span class="shortcode-user-level">';
    $output .= $current_user->display_name . "\n";
    $output .= "Level: {$current_user->level} \n <br>";
    $output .= '</span>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'userlevel', 'wpse_shortcode_userlevel' );
```

Then in your stylesheet add:

```
.shortcode-user-level {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Still going blank. Error logs point to the last line. add_shortcode() is an undefined function apparently?

Comment: Please paste the entire last line of your error log

Comment: [07-May-2014 00:41:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /Users/Sam/Documents/Uni Work/New Mamp Test Site/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4464

Comment: You've added the code in completely the wrong place. Remove any code you've added to that file. It should instead go inside functions.php inside your active theme folder. Go to /wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php and add it there. Never modify any core files (if it's in the wp-admin or wp-includes folder it shouldn't be changed).

Comment: Oh blimey what a fool! It's all working now. Nathan, thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Pleased I could help :)